# Use Javascript to copy Text from Label

Tags: asp.net, javascript

Label1 (asp.net control) is located inside Panel1 of my webpage and I have a button called bt.  What is the Javascript to copy the Text from Label1 to the clipboard?

@artlung, I placed the below code just outside of my form but inside the body.  The last line of code I placed inside Panel1 of my form.  Anything wrong with this code because nothing happens when I click the Copy to Clipboard button.

```
<script language="JavaScript"> 
                    var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client(); 
                    clip.addEventListener( 'mouseDown', function(client) {  
                            // set text to copy here 
                            clip.setText( document.getElementById('form1.Label1').value ); 

                            // alert("mouse down");  
                    } ); 

                    clip.glue( 'd_clip_button' ); 
            </script>
```

The next line of code is above the script tags but inside Panel1 in my form

```
<div id="d_clip_button">Copy To Clipboard</div>
```

Comment: FYI:  Programmatic access to the clipboard is dictated by the user.

Comment: I know this is done client side.  I've seen many sites on using javascript to copy text area but I was hoping to see Javascript copy the text from a Label using a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [zeroclipboard](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/) library.

Comment: isn't there some simple javascript that can accomplish this?

Comment: If there were, libraries such as zeroclipboard would not exist.

Comment: So following the instructions, if I set var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client(); do you know how I can set clip to copy Label1.Text? I was going to use a button called bt and on its onclick event set it to the zeroclipboard somehow but I don't know the syntax

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Read the instructions carefully: http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/wiki/Instructions you'll be calling `setText()` for the button. It depends on what the button id is, what other libraries you might have included.

Comment: so on my button onclick="setText()" ?  Then in my Javascript tag I just need to set var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client(); and clip.setText('Label1.Text');  ?  This doesn't seem to work and  have tried many different ways.  Do you have the correct syntax for this?

Comment: No, you can't just call setText() like that. You REALLY need to read the instructions. Failing that, have a look at the examples provided: http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/wiki/Instructions#Minimal_Example and http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/wiki/Instructions#Complete_Example

Comment: I DID read the instructions... I'm sorry if I overlooked anything but I'm just asking for some simple syntax help.  THANKS..

Comment: So what errors are you getting? Use Firefox and the JavaScript console and report back the errors.

Comment: I pasted my code at the top as that is the only place I knew to paste it.  Do you see any problems with it?

Comment: this worked.  thanks artlung  clip.setText( document.getElementById("Label1").innerHTML );

Comment: @Josh, great! I often find it frustrating implementing someone else's library. Way to stick to it!

Answer (score 2):

I achieved this with javascript.  I picked up on the fact that javascript was renaming the label from Label1 to MainContent_Label1.  Then I also through debugging saw that what I wanted to grab from the variable was the innerText property.  Problem Solved!

I also had the function test for an empty string and then return a confirmation alert to the user when they either copied successfully to the clipboard or when the label was empty with nothing to copy.  This is all client-side.

```
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Copy This!!!"></asp:Label>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      function ClipBoardTest() {
          var txt = document.getElementById('MainContent_Label1');
          window.clipboardData.setData("Text", txt.innerText);
          if(!txt){
              alert("Nothing to Copy");
              }
          else {
              alert("Copy to ClipBoard Successful!");
              }
      } 
    </script> 

    <input type="button" id='bt' onclick="ClipBoardTest();" value="Copy" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a way to copy text from label without using any external libraries.

```
copyStrFunction = (copyStr) => {
    const el = document.createElement('textarea'); // Create a <textarea> element
    el.value = copyStr;  // Set its value to the string that you want copied
    el.setAttribute('readonly', ''); // Make it readonly to be tamper-proof
    el.style.position = 'absolute'; 
    el.style.left = '-9999px'; // Move outside the screen to make it invisible
    document.body.appendChild(el); // Append the <textarea> element to the HTML document
    el.select(); // Select the <textarea> content
    document.execCommand('copy'); // Copy - only works as a result of a user action (e.g. click events)
    document.body.removeChild(el); // Remove the <textarea> element
}
```

Call the copyStrFunction() onclick of any button and the string. 
You can also modify the above function to find the label by Id and then copying the text from it.